# Spring boot not using application.properties in integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I have an issue with Spring boot not reading `application.properties` and `application-test.properties` during tests.

Here is my test class:

```
public class SignupRestControllerTest extends AbstractEnd2EndIntegrationTest {
 ...
```

and here is the `AbstractEnd2EndIntegrationTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.TEST)// "test"
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractEnd2EndIntegrationTest {

}
```

One can see that I do use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` so my test should be using Spring boot...

I use gradle to run the tests:

```
  sourceSets {

        main {
            output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
        }

        integrationTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/it/resources', 'src/main/resources']
            compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
        }
    }

   task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        description "Run the integration tests."
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/integration")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/integration")
    }
```

from `application.properties` (in `src/main/resources`):

```
database.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Exception I get:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: shouldn't it just be hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy?

Comment: Thanks. It is actually a custom property that I retrieve with a @Value.

Comment: By the way are arbitrary/custom properties resolved the same way by spring boot during tests?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this and resolved it by adding `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` to `@ContextConfiguration`.  The resulting annotation in this case would be:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(
classes = TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration.class,
initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```